# I am trying to install cordova plugin but unable to install it

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i am trying to install cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-buildinfo in my project but whenever i try to install it i am getting this exception.

```
(node:4356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Current working 
 directory is not a Cordova-based project.
at Object.cdProjectRoot 
(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova- 
lib\src\cordova\util.js:170:15)
at 
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova- 
lib\src\cordova\plugin\index.js:36:40
at _fulfilled 

(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova- 
 lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
 at self.promiseDispatch.done 

(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova- 
lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch 
(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova- 
lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
at 
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova- 
lib\node_modules\q\q.js:810:14
at flush 

(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova- 
lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
```

Comment: make sure your pwd is the root of your ionic project.

Comment: Check your path to the project is right or not.